# Access Javascript function return value in Elixir/Phoenix controller

Tags: javascript, html, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am using `Stripe.js` to make payment in my phoenix application.

I want to use the `tokenized` payment method, for this I have to pass the `card` information in a form and make a call to `Stripe.createToken(card)` method.

Once, I receive the token I want to use it in one of the controllers of my phoenix application. I don't have much experience with phoenix. Can somebody, suggest how to pass the token I receive from `Stripe.createToken(card)` into the controller?

code for `page.html`

```
<form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="card-element">
      Credit or debit card
    </label>
    <div id="card-element">
      <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>

    <!-- Used to display form errors -->
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit Payment</button>
  </form>
```

js code

```
// Create a Stripe client
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xx96UepEgmX12vaKbpJp1p70');

// Create an instance of Elements
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
var style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    lineHeight: '18px',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '16px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

// Create an instance of the card Element
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>
card.mount('#card-element');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

// Handle form submission
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    console.log('card-result', result);
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server
    }
  });
```

Comment: You can use  plugin to save the token  and use that plugin in the controller.

Comment: Just do a regular ajax request, or redirect to another page and put the token in either a get or post variable.

Comment: Ok, it came to my mind but I didn't know whether it was the right approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So, in your `stripe.createToken().then()` promise callback you can send the token to your server.

I use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), but you can use [plain JS XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started), or [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), or whatever you want.

#### Example:

```
stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
  console.log('card-result', result);
  if (result.error) {
    // Inform the user if there was an error
    var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
  } else {
    axios.post('/my-route-to-controller', {card_token: result.token})
      .then(function (response) {
        // do something with success
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // do something with error
      })
  }
});
```

Then you make sure you have `/my-route-to-controller` in your Router and your controller function will look something like:

```elixir
def create(conn, %{"card_token" => card_token}) do
  # do something with your `card_token`
end
```

Although you will probably want to submit more params. Just add them to the ajax request and match them in your controller.

#### Solution 2

Another option would be to add the token value to a hidden form input and just submit the form.